# how to make embed code for search function from another site...?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, symfony

Is there a possible way that if a shopping website has a "search function for an item" then can i embed the code into my website in a way that it shows the results on my website.

Like: embed fluege.de search function into my website... I have no access to their db or API. all i can do is inspect from firebug and build on my website(non-commercial it's only for learning purpose).

Something like this:

http://i58.tinypic.com/70l89s.jpg

Would be great if some1 would guide me like how to get started and what things I should be careful of.

Thanks.

Edit: I want to take a simple project based on symfony to understand the framework better.

Comment: Has this site an API to interface with?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do this. Why do you ask?

Comment: i want to take a simple project based on symfony like take fluege.de search function and embed into my website.

Comment: I think you should handle request from your form and perform request to shop, get html and process it to display (parsing etc.).

Comment: @user73595: If your aim is to get a better understanding of Symfony, you're much better of following the cookbook (AcmeDemoBundle), instead of focusing on a single detail, that most of us would solve using a plugin/bundle, or even an iframe or custom google search

Comment: Well ultimately I have to built something similar to the website i have discussed above.

Comment: @user73595: Yes, but most of us look for existing bundles before writing this ourselves. Using bundles correctly, and determining their suitability requires some knowledge of Symfony, so I suggest you start there